# Exporting current map extent or bookmark to polygon feature using existing tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, bookmarks

Is there a out-of-the-box tool in ArcGIS 10 (Editor) that would allow me to easily create a polygon feature from the current map extent or to convert a bookmark to a polygon feature.

I am not interested in a programmatic or a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no inbuilt tool for this.
There are ways and means to do it programmatically or through the UI in a round about way, but no out of the box tool will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I setup my bookmarks, then went through each of them in layout view and added a graphic rectangle to the extent of the data frame (by double clicking inside the frame and using the draw tools). I then converted the graphics to polygon features and added attributes for name and scale. The resulting feature class can be used for Data Driven Pages. It's not exact, but it is a possible solution.